# Duplicated page elements

Tags: html, .htaccess, boonex-dolphin

I am working in boonex dolphin 7.0 in my site when I am taking photos module by this URL:

```
http://www.sportzshowcase.com/sports/m/photos
```

Page getting duplicated, Is that htaccess problem ?

Answer (score 1):

copy the htaccess file from from original dolphin base folder and paste in your localhost project and  run project......otherwise change apache httpd.cof file setting(LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so)